# Checking Parameter Type in SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Is it possible to type check a SQL Parameter in a query?

(Why I'm asking) I'm implementing a universal search bar in my application. Because certain parts of my application have different displays, I was going to query my DB to see what my search term is in the DB and then return the appropriate Display Name.

So far I just have a bunch of if and else if statements checking to see if the search term is a value in a column in a specific table. I return the display Name and the column name. The issue is that different columns have different types and I'm not sure what type is being queried on.
For example, in my query below, SalesOrder is of type nvarchar and CID is of type int. So when I query with a nvarchar type and the previous if statements don't return anything then an error will be throw trying to compare a int with a nvarchar.

```
BEGIN
IF (SELECT COUNT([Part Number]) FROM Part WHERE [Part Number]=@Search) > 0
    SELECT 'Part Part Number'
ELSE IF (SELECT COUNT([Material Name]) FROM Part WHERE [Material Name]=@Search) > 0
    SELECT 'Inventory Material'
ELSE IF (SELECT COUNT(SalesOrder) FROM Part WHERE SalesOrder=@Search) > 0
    SELECT 'Order SalesOrder'
ELSE IF (SELECT COUNT(CID) FROM CustomerInfo WHERE CID=@Search) > 0
    SELECT 'Customer CID'
ELSE IF SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM CustomerInfo WHERE Name=@Search) > 0
    SELECT 'Customer Customer'
ELSE
    SELECT NULL
END
```

Maybe a better approach would be to type check in my applications language (C#) and then perform a specified search query on that type (This is what I'm going to do), but I'm also interested if this is a limitation of sql.

The reason I don't know the parameter data type is because System.Data.SqlClient.SQLParameter allows me to pass the name of parameter and a object to be assigned to that name. This allows for dynamic parameter typing because the objects type will be inferred by the Microsoft .NET Framework. As Larnu mentioned in the comments below, SQL doesn't normally allow dynamic typing but because I'm using a C# library that can infer data type, I get the dynamic typing as a side effect.

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you know what the data type of a parameter is? You have to be explicit on the data type in the procedures definition. You can't have `@Parameter {Data type of literal passed}`.

Comment: T-SQL does not like dynamic anything. The closest thing it has to this is the `SQL_VARIANT` type (which can hold any value) and `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY` (which can give you type information) but crucially, to use what's in a `SQL_VARIANT` you still typically have to cast it to an appropriate type first. A simple equality search happens to be one of the few scenarios where this is not needed, so you could conceivably use it (but take care then that, e.g., `1 <> '1'`, since there is no conversion). I still wouldn't recommend it as long as your client side can take care of it.

Comment: Maybe by using TRY_CONVERT/TRY_CAST?  F. e. `WHERE [Part Number]=TRY_CAST(@Search AS INT)`

Comment: It seems you are creating a dynamic search application. You could store the meta-data (table name, column name, data type, max length, precision, scale) in a user table.

Comment: @Larnu I added my answer to your question in the edit section of my question so that everyone sees it because it is a solid point that wouldn't normally happen in vanilla sql.

Comment: This has **significantly** changed the question then, @anonymousCoder . You aren't talking about SQL parameters (defined in a Stored procedure) you're talking about a *parametrised query* generated in C#. This pretty much invalidates @Garethd@s answer, and smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). Sounds like you should be creating an appropriate query in your application.

Comment: Can you post your c# code? As Larnu says, this feels a bit like an xy problem.

Comment: @Larnu Actually, not really.  While yes your interpretation was skewed without that information (Sorry for that)  It doesn't change my question at all: Can sql check for typing? Garethd assumed that I was passing  a nvarchar(which I can easily do by passing a string type before the type is inferred to ensure that it is nvarchar) Which then I can type cast it to anther type in the sql query. Meaning that I can query for that type. As for the XY problem, maybe in the big picture of what I'm doing (what project doesn't have this issue) but if you read the initial question; you'll see it's binary

Comment: I disagree, @anonymousCoder . This *is* an XY problem. The problem you're trying to solve, problem Y, is "How do I get SQL Server infer the data type of a parameter passed from C# so that it doesn't generate errors". Where as the problem you should be asking about, problem X, is "How do I pass the appropriate query to SQL Server based on the value of the parameter(s) I want to pass?" If you pass an appropriate query there is no need to write a pseudo catch-all query with multiple scans of your table; you can just use the appropriate query.

Comment: Agreed: just decide on the C# side what query to run

Comment: @Larnu I'm sorry but your just wrong. I've plainly stated that I want to know if sql can check for typing? That is problem X. 
            Because then I can run specified queries on that variable if I know the type.
            IF it's of type nvarchar THEN don't check if it's a value in a column of type int (plain and simple).
            Your confused because I added background about what framework I'm using that adds side effects to how I can create parameters in sql.

Comment: This is why you think my problem X is Y because your stuck on thinking that I don't know the type that is being inferred. 
            
            I can set the type of my search parameter to anything (String,int,float, etc) which is then infered by the framework to whatever the equivlent is in sql. 
            At that point you can forget c# had anything to do wtih this query. Now on the sql side what we have is search parameter that could be any type.

Comment: How do you handle a any type parameter. Well in any other language I would type check and perform what ever specifc operations I would need to do for that type.
            Hence can I type check in sql. Honestly I still don't know the answer to that but Garthd provided something that works by casting.

Comment: C# made it so if don't the parameters type in the query on the sql side but how the query is executed is vanillia sql. i'll change my quetion later to better reflect this but 
            honestly if you don't understand what I'm working with you need to ask more quetions instead of assuming. If there is a quetion Y, don't try to resolve X. That is wasting time.

Comment: *"How do you handle a any type parameter"* you don't, SQL (Server) has no such thing. You pass a strongly typed value. The fact you *want* to pass a non strongly typed parameter is evidence of the XY problem.

Comment: @Larnu Ok your missing the point. The reason it's any is becasue it could be any sql typing

Comment: If not an XY problem, you are asking the wrong question, as Larnu has pointed out, your SQL does know the type of the parameter, your problem is that you don't know what the type of the parameter is. It is not possible to declare dynamically typed in SQL therefore there is no way of retrieving the type of a parameter. This is not a "limitation" of SQL, it is a completely redundant requirement. The dynamic typing is done in c# and from c# you can retrieve the type e.g. `var type = command.Parameters.Add("@Search", obj).SqlDbType;`, but not really sure how that helps you solve your problem.

Comment: @GarethD Obviously this was the wrong place to ask such a niche question.  "your SQL does know the type of the parameter, your problem is that you don't know what the type of the parameter is". It sounds like you are making some grounds in understanding what I'm asking.  OK so if I don't know the type what is the next logical question? What is the type...(SMFH). As I stated in my OP the work around is to check in C# (which I did) but out of curiosity can sql do that for me.  Thank you for finally getting to the point...it can't because it wasn't designed that way. Hence it's a limitation.

Comment: @anonymousCoder I think I have addressed your questions in my 3rd edit. I appreciate your frustration with trying to get an answer to your question, but people are only trying to be helpful. If you walk into a hardware shop and ask what the best hammer is to drive in a screw, I would expect the staff to point out that you might actually want a screwdriver, and to ask a few ore questions about why you want to use a hammer to drive in a screw. If you insist on using a hammer, then you may well get the screw in, but it won't be as good a job as if you had used the right tool.

Answer (score 3):

---

### ANSWER ATTEMPT 1

If my understanding is correct, that you have a text input in your application, and are passing this text verbatim to SQL, then the type of `@Search` would likely be `NVARCHAR(200)` to catch all search terms. The length may vary, but I can't imagine people searching for much more than 200 characters at a time.

If my understanding is correct, you can infer a type by trying to convert it, e.g.

```
DECLARE @i INT = TRY_CONVERT(INT, @Search)
```

If `@i` is not null then `@Search` is an int, and you can use the parameter `@i` to search on any `int` columns you have. I'd also be inclined to `UNION` your results together rather than than do `IF`. Suppose you have a material name that is "Steel", and you also have a customer whose last name is "Steel", then at present you'll only return the row from `Part`, and mis any other matches, and you would have no idea what the user actually intended. Something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UniversalSearch @Search NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @i INT = TRY_CONVERT(INT, @Search),
            @dt DATETIME = TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, @Search);

    SELECT SourceTable = 'Part', SourceColumn = 'Part Number', Matches = COUNT(*)
    FROM    Part 
    WHERE   [Part Number] = @i
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SourceTable = 'Part', SourceColumn = 'Material Name', Matches = COUNT(*)
    FROM    Part 
    WHERE   [Material Name]=@Search
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  SourceTable = 'Part', SourceColumn = 'Sales Order', Matches = COUNT(*)
    FROM    Part
    WHERE   SalesOrder = @i
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  SourceTable = 'CustomerInfo', SourceColumn = 'CID', Matches = COUNT(*)
    FROM    CustomerInfo
    WHERE   CID = @i
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  SourceTable = 'CustomerInfo', SourceColumn = 'CID', Matches = COUNT(*)
    FROM    CustomerInfo
    WHERE   CreatedDate = @dt;

END
```

As long as everything you are searching for is indexed (and you use the appropriate variable in each search) you should get reasonable performance out of this, since you are now searching on the right types.

---

### ANSWER ATTEMPT 2

SQL does not have dynamic typing, the dynamic typing is being done by c#, and in c# you can retrieve what the type is before it is sent to the server , e.g.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetSqlType(1)); // Int
        Console.WriteLine(GetSqlType("string")); //NvarChar
        Console.WriteLine(GetSqlType(DateTime.Now)); //DateTime
    }
    static SqlDbType GetSqlType(object obj)
    {
        return new SqlCommand().Parameters.Add("@Search", obj).SqlDbType;
    }
}
```

You *could* then pass this type to your SQL and build your query based on that type, but even this seems like overkill, since it is unlikely that you are actually receiving your parameters as an object (especially if from a text input) and you are doing more boxing/unboxing than is necessary. It would be interesting to know the steps leading up to actually calling the SQL to see how you are passing the data from the UI through to the SqlCommand, to see where in this process some smarter typing could take place.

---

### ANSWER ATTEMPT 3

It is possible to get the type of a variable if you select it into a table, then check the metadata for that table, i.e.

```
DECLARE @Search NVARCHAR(MAX);

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #T;

SELECT  Variable = @Search
INTO    #T;

SELECT  t.name,
        c.scale,
        c.precision,
        c.max_length
FROM    tempdb.sys.columns AS c
        INNER JOIN sys.types AS t
            ON t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
            AND t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
WHERE   c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T')
AND     c.name = 'Variable';
```

This is clunky and verbose. The reason that there is no simple way of doing this is that with SQL alone this is never a requirement. The type of a variable/parameter is always known, so having a way of checking something that is know is redundant in SQL. If you use other applications to generate sql dynamically, then can't use that SQL as you like, that is not a limitation of SQL, but a limitation of the tool you are using. This is partly why `AddWithValue()` is generally advised against:

- [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/#:%7E:text=To%20follow%20best%20practices%2C%20avoid,and%20worth%20a%20few%20keystrokes.)
- [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Assuming you are stuck with this approach and have used the above to identify the type, it is still not that useful, you then need to do a load of conditional checks to work out when you can actually use it, like:

```
IF @TypeName IN ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar')
BEGIN
     -- Run queries that treat @search as a string
END
ELSE IF @TypeName IN ('int', 'smallint', 'tinyint', 'bigint', 'decimal', 'float')
BEGIN 
      --Run queries that treat @search as a number
END
-- etc
```

This doesn't really offer any benefits to identifying the type in c# and passing it to the procedure as above, it is just a bit more verbose.

So if identifying the type in c#, or SQL is not that useful, then what is? If it were me, I would probably have multiple procedures, but failing that you could create a procedure that takes different parameter types:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UniversalSearch 
       @SearchNVarchar NVARCHAR(200),
       @SearchInt INT,
       @SearchDateTime DATETIME,
       @SearchDecimal DECIMAL(38, 18)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT SourceTable = 'Part', SourceColumn = 'Part Number', Matches = COUNT(*)
    FROM    Part 
    WHERE   [Part Number] = @SearchInt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SourceTable = 'Part', SourceColumn = 'Material Name', Matches = COUNT(*)
    FROM    Part 
    WHERE   [Material Name]=@SearchNvarchar
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  SourceTable = 'Part', SourceColumn = 'Sales Order', Matches = COUNT(*)
    FROM    Part
    WHERE   SalesOrder = @SearchInt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  SourceTable = 'CustomerInfo', SourceColumn = 'CID', Matches = COUNT(*)
    FROM    CustomerInfo
    WHERE   CID = @SearchInt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  SourceTable = 'CustomerInfo', SourceColumn = 'CID', Matches = COUNT(*)
    FROM    CustomerInfo
    WHERE   CreatedDate = @SearchDateTime;

END
```

You've not posted your c# code, so will have to make some guesses about how you are getting your dynamic type there, but you could do something like:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.UniversalSearch", connection))
{
     connection.Open();
     var intParam = command.Parameters.Add("@SearchInt", SqlDbType.Int);
     var nvarcharParam = command.Parameters.Add("@SearchNVarchar", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200);
     var decParam = command.Parameters.Add("@SearchInt", SqlDbType.Decimal);
     var dateTimeParam = command.Parameters.Add("@SearchInt", SqlDbType.DateTime);

    if (obj is int)
         intParam.Value = obj;
    else if (obj is decimal)
         decParam.Value = obj;
    else if (obj is DateTime)
         dateTimeParam.Value = obj;
    else
         nvarcharParam.Value = obj;

}
```

It is really difficult to suggest the right way of doing this for you though, as you've only shown us a very small piece of the puzzle.

Finally, if your question is simply, can I get the type of the variable in SQL or is it a limitation that I can't?

Then Yes you can (as above), but it is not simple. I would not consider this a limitation of SQL though. Suppose I send my car off to another company to make it amphibious, but when it hits the water I realise that there is no rudder so I can't steer it. It is not a limitation of my car that it does not have a rudder, my car when used as built does not need a rudder. It's not a great analogy, but the best I could think of. Basically, Microsoft have created this awful AddWithValue method that has given the ability to people to do something that SQL was never designed to do. If this then generates problems, it lies solely at the door of `AddWithValue` and not with SQL.

Comment: `@i` is predefined as an `int` here though, so a cause like `WHERE   [Material Name]=@Search` is likely to generate an error; I doubt a column with a name like `Material Name` has an `int` value. You can't convert the value `'Steel'` or `'Wood'` to an `int`.

Comment: My inference is that `@Search` is `NVARCHAR()` and comes from the text input into the users *"universal search bar"* in the application, and they say *"So when I query with a nvarchar type"...*. I will clarify my interpretation in the answer though

Comment: Not your fault, but the OP has completely moved the goal posts. It's not an `(n)varchar` parameter, it's a parametrised query and the OP is dynamically changing the data type of the parameters define in the C# code... They weren't talking about SQL parameter (such as those as part of a Stored Procedure) at all; the fact this was coming from a .Net application was completely omitted in their question.